# How to add gradient to container and image in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to replicate the design below [image: card to replicate] in my flutter application but stuck at the point of adding the background color and the tiny diamonds with transparent backgrounds.
My code so far uses a plain background with a font color that does not match.

I have tried to give the container a linear background color but it does not unfortunately look like the design above.
Also I have tried to draw some diamonds with the canvas.drawPath() but can't figure out how to arrange it to make it look like what is in the image.

Here is my code below (`cc` is `Colors.blueGrey`):

```
Container(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              border: Border.all(
                                                width: 0.1,
                                                color: i % 2 == 0 ? Colors.transparent : Colors.black,
                                              ),
                                              boxShadow: const [
                                                BoxShadow(
                                                  spreadRadius: 0.1,
                                                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                                                  blurRadius: 0.5,
                                                  offset: Offset(0, 0),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                                Radius.circular(10),
                                              ),
                                              color: i % 2 == 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.blueGrey,
                                              // color: i % 2 == 0 ? Colors.white : const Color.fromARGB(255, 2, 48, 71).lighten(3),
                                            ),
                                            child: Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                                              child: Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Row(
                                                    // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                                    children: [
                                                      const Image(
                                                        image: AssetImage('./assets/svg/diamond.png'),
                                                        height: 30,
                                                        width: 30,
                                                      ),
                                                      const SizedBox(width: 20),
                                                      Column(
                                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                        children: [
                                                          Text(
                                                            'Diamond Premium',
                                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                              fontSize: 18,
                                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                              color: cc,
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                          Container(
                                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                              color: Colors.green[800],
                                                              border: Border.all(
                                                                color: Colors.greenAccent.shade100.withAlpha(50),
                                                                width: 0.5,
                                                              ),
                                                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                                                Radius.circular(20),
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
                                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 2, 5, 2),
                                                            child: Text(
                                                              'Current',
                                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                                color: cc,
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                  const SizedBox(
                                                    height: 30,
                                                  ),
                                                  Column(
                                                    children: [
                                                      Row(
                                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                        children: [
                                                          Row(
                                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                            children: [
                                                              Icon(
                                                                Icons.money_rounded,
                                                                color: cc,
                                                                size: 16,
                                                              ),
                                                              const SizedBox(
                                                                width: 5,
                                                              ),
                                                              Text(
                                                                'Cost',
                                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                                  color: cc,
                                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                                ),
                                                              )
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                          Text(
                                                            '\$40,000.00',
                                                            style: TextStyle(color: cc, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                                                          ),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                      Padding(
                                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 5),
                                                        child: DottedLine(
                                                          dashColor: cc,
                                                          lineThickness: 0.4,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      Row(
                                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                        children: [
                                                          Row(
                                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                            children: [
                                                              Icon(
                                                                Icons.lock_clock,
                                                                color: cc,
                                                                size: 16,
                                                              ),
                                                              const SizedBox(
                                                                width: 5,
                                                              ),
                                                              Text(
                                                                'Duration',
                                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                                  color: cc,
                                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                                ),
                                                              )
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                          Text(
                                                            '40 days',
                                                            style: TextStyle(color: cc, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                                                          ),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                      Padding(
                                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 5),
                                                        child: DottedLine(
                                                          dashColor: cc,
                                                          lineThickness: 0.4,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      Padding(
                                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 5),
                                                        child: DottedLine(
                                                          dashColor: cc,
                                                          lineThickness: 0.4,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      Row(
                                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                        children: [
                                                          Row(
                                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                            children: [
                                                              Icon(
                                                                Icons.forward,
                                                                color: cc,
                                                                size: 16,
                                                              ),
                                                              const SizedBox(
                                                                width: 5,
                                                              ),
                                                              Text(
                                                                'Cash Out',
                                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                                  color: cc,
                                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                                ),
                                                              )
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                          Text(
                                                            '\$40.00 - \$100.00',
                                                            style: TextStyle(color: cc, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                                                          ),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                      Padding(
                                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 5),
                                                        child: DottedLine(
                                                          dashColor: cc,
                                                          lineThickness: 0.4,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),

                                                      const SizedBox(
                                                        height: 5,
                                                      ),
                                                      Container(
                                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                                        color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.1),
                                                        child: Column(
                                                          children: [
                                                            Row(
                                                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                              children: [
                                                                Row(
                                                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                                  children: [
                                                                    Icon(
                                                                      Icons.select_all_sharp,
                                                                      color: cc,
                                                                      size: 16,
                                                                    ),
                                                                    const SizedBox(
                                                                      width: 5,
                                                                    ),
                                                                    Text(
                                                                      'Watch',
                                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                                        color: cc,
                                                                        fontSize: 14,
                                                                      ),
                                                                    )
                                                                  ],
                                                                ),
                                                                Text(
                                                                  '\$0.005',
                                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                                    color: cc,
                                                                    fontSize: 14,
                                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                                                  ),
                                                                ),
                                                              ],
                                                            ),
                                                            const SizedBox(
                                                              height: 5,
                                                            ),
                                                            Row(
                                                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                              children: [
                                                                Row(
                                                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                                  children: [
                                                                    Icon(
                                                                      Icons.select_all_sharp,
                                                                      color: cc,
                                                                      size: 16,
                                                                    ),
                                                                    const SizedBox(
                                                                      width: 5,
                                                                    ),
                                                                    Text(
                                                                      'Share',
                                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                                        color: cc,
                                                                        fontSize: 14,
                                                                      ),
                                                                    )
                                                                  ],
                                                                ),
                                                                Text(
                                                                  '\$0.1',
                                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                                    color: cc,
                                                                    fontSize: 14,
                                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                                                  ),
                                                                ),
                                                              ],
                                                            ),
                                                            const SizedBox(height: 5),
                                                            Row(
                                                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                              children: [
                                                                Row(
                                                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                                  children: [
                                                                    Icon(
                                                                      Icons.select_all_sharp,
                                                                      color: cc,
                                                                      size: 16,
                                                                    ),
                                                                    const SizedBox(
                                                                      width: 5,
                                                                    ),
                                                                    Text(
                                                                      'Click',
                                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                                        color: cc,
                                                                        fontSize: 14,
                                                                      ),
                                                                    )
                                                                  ],
                                                                ),
                                                                Text(
                                                                  '\$0.0005',
                                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                                    color: cc,
                                                                    fontSize: 14,
                                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                                                  ),
                                                                ),
                                                              ],
                                                            ),
                                                          ],
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      const SizedBox(
                                                        height: 10,
                                                      ),
                                                      


                                                      // button goes here
                                                      // okay
                                                      SizedBox(
                                                        width: double.infinity,
                                                        child: OutlinedButton(
                                                          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                                                            foregroundColor: Colors.green,
                                                          ),
                                                          onPressed: () => false,
                                                          child: const Text('Upgrade'),),
                                                      ),
                                                      
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

The easier way is to use a ready-made svg for the background rather than redesign.

https://www.vectorstock.com/royalty-free-vector/abstract-gradient-triangle-background-vector-15671257

For example, if you directly use an svgye as a background, as in the link I left below, you will get a faster result. You can also produce your own svg files. You can get faster results with these methods.